# Why am I getting flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "application" ImportError was raised?

Tags: python, flask

I received this error after correcting one related to SQLAlchemy:

```
flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "application", an ImportError was raised:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/Ryan/Desktop/HCS/project/application.py", line 6, in <module>
    from passlib.apps import custom_app_context as pwd_context
ImportError: No module named 'passlib'
```

The passlib module **is** in: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask`

The environment variable is set at FLASK_APP=application.py. This was set while in the folder to which flask was installed. I've tried manually placing the file in the above referenced folder and using pip to no avail. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [passlib](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is a separate library. It should not be **in** flask. Try installing it:

```
pip install passlib
```

Comment: Used that command. There was a version sitting in something like Python > 3.6 > Site-Packages. I'm ripping everything out (that didn't come with Mac) and reinstalling everything that's required for this project. This is ridiculous. I've never had this issue with Flask, Python, passlib, or whatever before.

Comment: Are you not using a virtual environment? If so, I highly suggest you you look into it. You can have isolated disposable environments per project so you don't have to touch python that came with your mac.